# URL Rewrite doesn't work as intended apache2

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Works:

```
 RewriteRule  index2.php/xyz/ index2.php/?pt=xyz [QSA,L]
```

Doesn't Work:

```
 RewriteRule  index2.php/(.+)$/ index2.php/?pt=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried to use the above rewrite rule but somewhy it doesn't work... $1 stays null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the `$` in there after `(.+)`? Dollar sign means end of line in most regex engines. What happens if you take that out?

Comment: Seems like I went full retarded on this one, thanks, when I placed the $ in the proper place it worked!